# Why does my DynamoDB secondary index only work with a partial part of the sort key

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Querying a table on Secondary Index, using a BeginsWith Operator does not always return the correct records. What could be the reason for that?

I have sample Code and tried it against a local DynamoDB table and against a table in AWS. The results are the same.

Defining the secondary index:

```
        var gsiKey1Index = new GlobalSecondaryIndex
        {
            IndexName = "GSIKey1Index",
            ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
            {
                ReadCapacityUnits = 1,
                WriteCapacityUnits = 1
            },
            Projection = new Projection { ProjectionType = "ALL" }
        };

        var indexKey1Schema = new List<KeySchemaElement> {
            {
                new KeySchemaElement
                {
                    AttributeName = "HashKey", KeyType = KeyType.HASH
                }
            },  //Partition key
            {
                new KeySchemaElement
                {
                    AttributeName = "GSISortKey1", KeyType = KeyType.RANGE
                }
            }  //Sort key
        };
        gsiKey1Index.KeySchema = indexKey1Schema;
```

Creating the table:

```
        var request = new CreateTableRequest
        {
            TableName = "TestTable",
            AttributeDefinitions = new List<AttributeDefinition>
            {
                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "HashKey",
                    // "S" = string, "N" = number, and so on.
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },
                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                    AttributeName = "SortKey",
                    AttributeType = "S"
                },
                new AttributeDefinition
                {
                AttributeName = "GSISortKey1",
                // "S" = string, "N" = number, and so on.
                AttributeType = "S"
            },

            },
            KeySchema = new List<KeySchemaElement>
            {
                new KeySchemaElement
                {
                    AttributeName = "HashKey",
                    // "HASH" = hash key, "RANGE" = range key.
                    KeyType = "HASH"
                },
                new KeySchemaElement
                {
                    AttributeName = "SortKey",
                    KeyType = "RANGE"
                },
            },
            GlobalSecondaryIndexes = { gsiKey1Index },
            ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
            {
                ReadCapacityUnits = 10,
                WriteCapacityUnits = 5
            },
        };


        response2 = await _client.CreateTableAsync(request);
```

The Entity looks like this:

```
[DynamoDBTable("TestTable")]
public sealed class TestResult
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string HashKey {get;set;}
    public string SortKey {get;set;}
    public string GSISortKey1 {get; set;}
}
```

The code to query looks like this:

```
    public async Task<List<TestResult>> GetTestResultByDateTimeAsync(Guid hashid, Guid someId, string someName, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        var key2 = $"TR-{someId}-{someName}-{timestamp:yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffZ}";
        var key = $"TR-{someId}-{someName}-{timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd}";
        //var filter = new QueryFilter();
        //filter.AddCondition("HashKey", ScanOperator.Equal, hashid.ToString());
        //filter.AddCondition("GSISortKey1", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, key);
        //var queryConfig = new QueryOperationConfig
        //{
        //    Filter = filter
        //};
        DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
        {
            OverrideTableName = "DEVTransponderTR",
            IndexName = "GSIKey1Index",
            QueryFilter = new List<ScanCondition>()
        };
        var sc = new ScanCondition("GSISortKey1", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, new[] { key });
        operationConfig.QueryFilter.Add(sc);
        var search = _context.QueryAsync<TestResult>(tenantid.ToString(), operationConfig);
        var testresults = await search.GetRemainingAsync();
        bool keywasok = true;
        foreach (var testresult in testresults)
        {
            keywasok = testresult.GSISortKey1.StartsWith(key2) && keywasok;
        }

        if (keywasok) // this means I should find the same values if I use key2
        {
            DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig2 = new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
            {
                OverrideTableName = "TestTable",
                IndexName = "GSIKey1Index",
                QueryFilter = new List<ScanCondition>()
            };
            var sc2 = new ScanCondition("GSISortKey1", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, new[] { key2 });
            operationConfig2.QueryFilter.Add(sc2);
            var search2 = _context.QueryAsync<TestResult>(tenantid.ToString(), operationConfig);
            var testresults2 = await search.GetRemainingAsync();


        }

        return testresults;
    }
```

Then I add three instances to the table. importants is that all information is the same except the GSISortKey1 value. This is the GSISortKey1 value for the three items:

"TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02T12:24:19.000Z-Open"
"TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02T12:24:19.000Z-Send"
"TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02T12:24:19.000Z-Test"

So in the example I first query on "BeginsWith" with a value of "TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02"  (this is var key)

It returns all three items.

Then I check if the whole GSISortKey1 value of three returned items would also begin with the value "TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02T12:24:19.000Z-", and that is true.

If that is true I just query again with a BeginsWith using the value "TR-0d798900-a852-4a75-bef0-5dd5c96c657c-Module1-2019-04-02T12:24:19.000Z-"

It should return all three items. it returns 0 items.

I guess I am doing something wrong, some help appreciated.

Comment: I assume there is no `LastEvaluatedKey` in the response?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it important?

Comment: A Scan response will contain a `LastEvaluatedKey` if there are more results. A response can actually return no results but still have results available. You have to paginate the Scan until there is no `LastEvaluatedKey` in the response.

Comment: It's my understanding that GetRemainingAsync does exactly that, it gets all the results.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I'm not familiar with the C# client

Comment: If I were debugging this myself, I'd look closer at the timestamp. Given it works without `THH\\:mm\\:ss.fffZ` but once you add that and nothing else has changed you get no results...your issue lies within that piece. 

Ensure that your strings are actually getting created the exact same way. Try hardcoding it and see if that works.  Without seeing the creation, it could be a bunch of things -- you might have a encoding issue, or hidden character of some sort when creating versus querying.